# How to save the image inside the dynamically created directory? How to save the path of the folder in DB?

Tags: php, html

I have uploads folder and inside there ,dynamically, I am creating another directory based on the image id.

I'm creating the directory but the image is not being saved in it! At the same time I want to store the path of the folder in the database.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

   $img_id=$_POST['img_id']; 

 /*  $imgpath= mkdir("uploads/".$img_id);
   $path1= "$imgpath/".$_FILES['c_photo']['name'][0];      
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['c_photo']['name'][0], $path1);    
    $img_photo=$_FILES['c_photo']['name'][0]; 
*/
```

// This code is saving the image in **uploads** folder instead off **$imgpath** directory

```
    $imgpath=mkdir("uploads/".$img_id);
   $path1="uploads/".$_FILES['c_photo']['name'][0];  
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['c_photo']['tmp_name'][0],$path1);


    $query1 ="INSERT INTO img_tbl(`img_id`,`img_photo`) VALUES ('$img_id', '$path1')";


    if ($conn->query($query1) === TRUE) {

        header("location:show_img.php?");

    }
    else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close(); 


}


?>

<div class="col-sm-12">                                        
    <div class="col-sm-3">
     <label>Image id</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
       <input class="form-control" type="text" name="img_id""/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
   <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label>Upload photo</label>
   </div>
 <div class="col-sm-9">
    <input class="form-control" type="file" name="c_photo[]" />
 </div>
</div>


<div class="col-sm-5">
  <input class="form-control" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"/>
</div>
```

Please help me. I am new in php. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you uploading a single or multiple files?

Comment: have you written your `html` inside `<form></form>`?

Answer (score 1):

The move_uploaded_file() needs a file name and a destination. I guess you 2. parameter is not good. You can read more about it here: [PHP move-uploaded-file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Try this:

```
$folderPath = "uploads/".$img_id;
$isimgpath= mkdir(folderPath); 

if(isimgpath){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['c_photo']['tmp_name'], $folderPath);
}
```

I guess your DB insert may work, but it fails before it and that's why it is not in. 
You can save image path to db. You create a "$path1" value, put it in the DB Insert. As i see it contains a image path with the name of it.

```
$query1 ="INSERT INTO img_tbl(`img_id`,`img_photo`) VALUES ('$img_id', ". $path1 .")";
```

Try to modify the input as well like this:

```
<input class="form-control" type="file" name="c_photo" />
```

Comment: image are not moving inside the dynamically created folder..please help me out

Comment: I edited my text, check it. Try to echo the "$imgpath" and "$_FILES['c_photo']['tmp_name']" somewhere. It these values are null, then it is another reason for your issue.

Comment: Oh, yep. The mkdir return with true, or false (1 or 0). This is the problem for move_uploaded_file. I modified the example.

Comment: **folderpath** directory is created outside of uploads folder and inside the **uploads** one file with img_id name created(but its not folder..it is file) and image inside it.

Comment: Its very minor mistake ..its creating  **file**  not folder **inside the uploads folder**.Please give some time to resolve my issue

Answer (score 0):

you have an issue with the uploading code it should be `tmp_name` which provide temporary store path from the server

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['c_photo']['tmp_name'][0], $path1);
```

Turn on your error reporting to display errors [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the form has the correct `enctype` attribute ( `multipart/form-data` ) and you are uploading a single file as opposed to using a loop to upload multiple files then perhaps the following might help a little ( not tested though )

```
<?php

    if( isset( $_POST['submit'], $_POST['img_id'] ) && !empty( $_FILES['c_photo'] ) ){

        /* for convenience, convert to an object to use Object notation */
        $obj=(object)$_FILES['c_photo'];
        $tmp=$obj->tmp_name;
        $name=$obj->name;
        $error=$obj->error;

        $img_id=$_POST['img_id']; /* peculiar knowing the ID before inserting into the database?? */

        $savepath=__DIR__ . '/uploads/' . $img_id;

        mkdir( $savepath, 0644 );/* create directory & set directory perms */

        $path = $savepath.'/'.$name; 

        $result = is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) & move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $path );
        if( $result ){
            $query ="INSERT INTO img_tbl( `img_id`, `img_photo` ) VALUES ('$img_id', '$name')";
            $result=$conn->query( $query );

            if( $result ){
                header( "location:show_img.php?img_id=".$img.id );
            } else {
                echo "Error: ";
            }
        }

        $conn->close(); 


    }
?>
```

Comment: still its creating only directory...image not saving in directory

Comment: silly me.. the return value of `mkdir` is a boolean - not the actual path. Changed the above code

Comment: It's not working for me..please guide if any other way possible